# loanform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cname'

Tags: django

I am trying to submit the form after entering the details but after submitting, it shows a TypeError msg like unexpected 
keywords arguments 'cname' in loanform(cname = name, email = email, mobile = mobile, scheme = scheme, city = city, msg = msg) method.

## My Model.Py File

```
class loanform(models.Model):
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    scheme = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cname
```

## My View.Py File

```
def loan_form(request):
    print("Form is Submitted.")
    name = request.POST.get("name",False)
    email = request.POST.get("email",False)
    mobile = request.POST.get("mobile",False)
    scheme = request.POST.get("scheme",False)
    city = request.POST.get("city",False)
    msg = request.POST.get("msg",False)
    lnform = loanform(cname = name, email = email, mobile = mobile, scheme = scheme, city = city, msg=msg)
    lnform.save()
    return render(request, 'loanform.html')
```

## My Url.Py File

```
path('loan_form/', views.loan_form, name='loan_form')
```

Comment: why don't you create a model form class and then save the post data ?

Comment: can u tell me how to create model form class @not2acoder

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform and the example

Comment: try `lnform = loanform.objects.create(cname = name, email = email, mobile = mobile, scheme = scheme, city = city, msg=msg)`

Comment: Thank you @Vaibhav Vishal for helping me and giving me ur time. I do what u have told me but it's shows an error like 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: why does it says loanform is a function. loanform should be a Class. Make sure you are importing loanform correctly or post your complete views.py. Also class names should follow PascalCase to avoid confusion, your model class name should be LoanForm

Comment: It's Working @Vaibhav Vishal. Thanks a lot for helping me.. Thank You

Comment: what exactly was wrong?

Comment: Nothing. I changed the name of class according to PascalCase and its working and the error 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' is also gone. Thank you once again @ Vaibhav Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Class names should follow PascalCase, so it should be `LoanForm`.

```
lnform = loanform.objects.create(cname=name, email=email, mobile=mobile, scheme=scheme, city=city, msg=msg)
```

Comment: It shows an error like  'dict' object has no attribute 'META' @Vaibhav Vishal